Artifact affects crew in outer space
Looked through dozens of lists but can't find it. What I recall is a somewhat common premise: a crew aboard a space-craft (think Nostromo from Alien) discover an alien(?) artifact that has a peculiar effect on the members of the crew a short time after being brought aboard (induces confusion / exerts control over free-will / or something like that).
iirc the artifact was a black cube.
Likely from the 90's.
(Not Event Horizon)

Was this a Hollywood movie?  Do you recall what language it was in?  Any recognizable actors?

I think you probably mean Supernova, with Robin Tunney, recently of Mentalist fame. Also Angela Bassett and James Spader. Released in 2000.
From imdb plot summary:

Supernova chronicles the search and rescue patrol of a medical ship in deep space in the early 22nd century and its six-member crew which includes a Captain and Pilot, a co-pilot, a medical officer, a medical technician, a search and rescue paramedic, and a computer technician. When their vessel, the Nightingale 229, answers an emergency distress signal from a comet mining operation in a distant galaxy, the crew soon finds itself in danger from the mysterious young man they rescue, the alien artifact he's smuggled aboard, and the gravitational pull of a giant star about to supernova. The resulting explosion will be the most massive explosion in the universe.


Could it have been Alien Cargo?  It was a UPN or WB movie in the late 90s.  If they stayed cold, the artifact didn't hurt them.  If they got hot, it made them murderously angry.  It ends with them flying into the sun.

Absolute shot in the dark, but could it be Hellraiser: Bloodline?

The film begins at Space Station Minos in the year 2127. Paul Merchant, the man who built the station, has a robot solve the Lament Configuration (the robot is subsequently destroyed); however, several guards led by Rimmer capture Paul. Paul tells Rimmer the story of his bloodline.

It's been forever since I watched it, but the box you're referring to might be the puzzle box in this film.
