# Help identify sci-fi movie

Tags: identify-this-movie

- English-language film
- American or UK
- Probably labelled a "B-grade sci-fi"
- Very likely 1990's
- "Alien" / "Event Horizon" 'feel' to it

The premise goes something like: Crew aboard spacecraft bring aboard unknown artifact discovered in space; [some] crew members begin exhibiting unusual psychological symptoms; violent shenanigans ensue.

Also, I *think* the artifact was a black sphere or cube -- something seemingly innocuous.

Comment: [A similar question was asked here before](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33416/artifact-affects-crew-in-outer-space/); see if any of the answers fits.

Comment: It sounds like Supernova but I would need more details to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Was it "The Sphere"? Released in 1998, based on a book by Michael Crichton. They find a space ship on the bottom of the ocean that has been there for at least 300 years. It turns out to be an American ship from the future that was collecting artifacts from around the galaxy. One of the artifacts was a perfect sphere. Basically it was a test from an alien species. If you touch it whatever you think about happens.

Answer (score 1):

[Supernova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova_%282000_film%29) is a "B" movie produced in 2000 about a rescue space ship that picks up an accident survivor and a mysterious artifact that inflicts much havoc on the crew and ship. It most definitely had "Event Horizons" color palette and a strong "Alien" wannabe feel to it.